# Using [(ngModel)] and having an empty select element

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-template-form

I am using [(ngModel)] top bind various inputs and select elements in my angular application.  I also use a service with ngModel.  When using the select element, my app is showing an empty option.

Even if I change the value of the first option to something other than an empty string, the same issue comes up.

```html
<div>
  <input 
    placeholder="Ohio Volume"
    type="number"
    class="text-input"
    value="{{ this.inputsService.ohioVolume }}"
    [(ngModel)]="ohioVolume"
    (change)="this.inputsService.setOhioVolume(ohioVolume)"
  >
</div>
<div>
  <select
    class="select" 
    value="{{ this.inputsService.ohioReporter }}"
    [(ngModel)]="ohioReporter"
    (change)="this.inputsService.setOhioReporter(ohioReporter)">
    <option value="">Ohio Reporter</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.3d">Ohio St.3d</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.2d">Ohio St.2d</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.">Ohio St.</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My inputsService typescript file shows in relevant part:

```
ohioReporter: string

setOhioReporter(ohioReporter) {
    this.ohioReporter = ohioReporter
}
```

The input code is working appropriately, but the select shows an empty box regardless of the value of the first option.  I would prefer the solution to remain only in the html code and not require any typescript code.

Comment: Do you have value on this `[(ngModel)]="ohioReporter"`? if not, that's why it shows empty.

Comment: could you maybe show the ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your ts/Service, maybe its because its not defined by default

```
   ohioReporter: string = ""
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  Regardless of the default value, I still get an empty element.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify yout code in this way:

```
 <select
    class="select" 
    value="{{ this.inputsService.ohioReporter }}"
formControlName="name" [ngModel]="ohioReporter" name="ohioReporter" (ngModelChange)="ohioReporter($event)">
    <option value="">Ohio Reporter</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.3d">Ohio St.3d</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.2d">Ohio St.2d</option>
    <option value="Ohio St.">Ohio St.</option>
  </select>
```

the .ts becames:

```
@Output() ohioReporter: number;

....
  ohioReporter(ohioReporter) {

    this.ohioReporter= ohioReporter;
}
```

Comment: That did not work.  I inject the service into the native typescript file so that may be why.

  constructor(private inputsService: Inputs) {}

I attempted the Output as you showed above.  Also, this is not a form.